# Battery loses power even when connected to a good power source

Tags: arch-linux, kde, power-management

I am running Arch linux on my Lenovo ideapad 320 with KDE as the GUI. My laptop is always connected to a good power source but for some reason it keeps losing power from the battery, i.e. 1% every 2 days. When I close all the applications and leave it charge, it does reach to 100%, so I'm not sure why it loses power in the first place.

I have TLP installed and enabled, so does anyone have any idea to fix this power problem? Or are there any certain packages I need to know about that drains the battery? 
 
 Here are some relevant info:

```
sudo tlp-stat
+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO Lenovo ideapad 320-15IKB 80XL
BIOS           = 4WCN47WW
Kernel         = 5.10.62-1-lts #1 SMP Fri, 03 Sep 2021 10:00:32 +0000 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = root=UUID=e87279ed-e340-4301-b3de-ddf89b45fb3d rw initrd=\intel-ucode.img initrd=\initramfs-linux-lts.img loglevel=3 quiet
Init system    = systemd 
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
RDW state      = not installed
Last run       = 16:04:16,    107 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC

lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  4
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               142
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  2
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            9
    CPU max MHz:         3100.0000
    CPU min MHz:         400.0000
```

When I switch to Windows it charges to 100% and never loses power.

Comment: might be a problem in the power supply

Comment: sorry I forgot to write that when I switch to Windows, it works perfectly fine, i.e. it charges to 100% and never lose power

Answer (score 0):

"It's not a bug, it's a feature". Modern devices purposely do this and I believe is implemented via hardware, not software. When a battery reaches 100% the charging stops allowing the battery to drain a little bit, then it will charge again to 100%, and repeat this constantly while the battery is connected to the power source in what is called a Trickle Charging process. This is also used in other types of batteries, like automotive batteries.

The reason is to prevent adverse effects on the life of the battery.

**More info >** https://sciencing.com/revive-lithium-ion-batteries-5982537.html

And here more specific info about Lenovo and ArchLinux in regards to  Battery Conservation Mode.

Disable Battery Convervation Mode:

```
echo '\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.VPC0.SBMC 5' | tee /proc/acpi/call
```

**Link >** https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_IdeaPad_720s

Comment: hm.. yea that used to happen on Windows, but the lowest it reached was 98%, but on Arch it could go as low as 80%, I'd have to re-plug my charger in order to get it charging again, is that normal then?

Comment: I have updated the answer, look at the link at the bottom in regards to Battery Conservation Mode in ArchLinux.